# Box.com - crawl all files changed since token

Tags: box

In box.com, I'm looking to search for a bunch of documents, get a token, then use that token in a later search to get all the new documents. A "detect changes" api. Google drive has something similar I believe.

Does box.com support this? Does it support giving us change deltas for deleted files, updated files, changed permissions/metadata/tags, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they do support this. Enterprise only Events API we're using it in production and it works great.